# Finding the least squares linear regression for each row of a dataframe in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have the a dataframe:

(day/month/year)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'Date0': ['01/01/1999','01/06/1999','01/01/1979'], 'V0': [29,44,21],
                   'Date1': ['08/01/2000','07/01/2000','01/01/2000'],'V1': [35, 45, 47]})
```

I want to interpolate the age for each row to find 'V_10' which is the value at the date 10/08/1999 using a linear regression. 
For example in the first case I would get something like:

```
Slope   0.01609
Y-intercept     29.00    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'Date0': ['01/01/1999','01/06/1999','01/01/1979'], 'V0': [29,44,21],
                   'Date1': ['08/01/2000','07/01/2000','01/01/2000'],'V1': [35, 45, 47], 
                   'V_10':[32.57]})
```

*I hope my calculations are correct.*

And what if I want an exponential regression or worse a custom function I have?

Comment: You have two variables, V0 and V1. Which one do you want to use to get V_10?

Comment: Both for each row I want to find the linear interpolation between V0 and V1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but for a linear interpolation you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
               'Date0': ['01/01/1999','01/06/1999','01/01/1979'], 'V0': [29,44,21],
               'Date1': ['08/01/2000','07/01/2000','01/01/2000'],'V1': [35, 45, 47]})
df['Target'] = pd.to_datetime('10/08/1999')
df['Date0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date0'])
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'])
df['Target'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Target'])

def regress(xs, ys, newx, reference=pd.to_datetime('1/1/1900'), retype='linear', fit_intercept=True, degree=None):
    xs = [(x - reference).days for x in xs]
    xs = np.array(xs).reshape(-1,1)
    ys = np.array(ys)
    if retype == 'linear':
        lm = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=fit_intercept)
    elif retype == 'polynomial':
        lm = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)),
                   ('linear', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=fit_intercept))])
    else:
        return print('Need to specify other regression type.')
    lm.fit(xs,ys)
    return lm.predict(np.array((newx - reference).days).reshape(-1, 1))[0]

# Linear regression example
df['V10'] = df.apply(lambda x: regress([x.Date0,x.Date1], [x.V0,x.V1], x.Target, retype='linear'), axis=1)
# 2nd-degree polynomial regression example
df['V11']=df.apply(lambda x: regress([x.Date0,x.Date1], [x.V0,x.V1], x.Target, retype='polynomial', degree=2), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, but what if want an exponential  interpolation or more broadly a non-linear interpolation?

Comment: See my updated answer.  I am now using scikit-learn to perform the regressions.  Inherently I've provided the ability to run linear and polynomial regressions; however, you can perform power and exponential regressions by adjusting the x and y variables (i.e., take log of one, the other, or both, depending on what you want). (Just be sure to adjust the predicted value accordingly.)